# Is it possible to quote a text in Gmail while preserving newlines?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to quote a text in Gmail while preserving newlines?

When I try to quote a text with the quote button, some newlines get removed:

[image]

If you want to try, here is the text I used in the animation above:

```
Hi,

Is it possible to insert two subsequent newlines in an arXiv abstract? For example, in the abstract of https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475 

Objective: Patient notes in electronic health records (EHRs) […]

Materials and Methods: We introduce the first […]

Results: Our ANN model outperforms […]

Conclusion: Our findings support the use […]

Thanks,
Franck
```

Comment: @pnuts I still have this issue, amongst many other formatting issues in that compose box.

Comment: @pnuts Interesting. On my side the issue is always present. I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate + chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't yet possible to quote a text in Gmail while preserving newlines. You have to wait for Google to fix the issue, amongst many other formatting issues in that compose box.

Answer (score 4):

I solve it by cutting the text I want quoted into clipboard, then create a blank quote in gmail and finally paste the text into the blank quote.